# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ejb/TimerConfig

Tags: maven, junit4, ejb-3.1

I have a EJB class which creates a timer using TimerService & TimerConfig of EJB.

When I am running the junit for testing the class, following error is seen :

java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ejb/TimerConfig

I am using below maven dependency for ejb :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.ejb</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any suggestion how to resolve the issue??

Answer (score 2):

Methods in classes coming from javax:javaee-api dependency are empty shells - they do not have real implementation. These classes are only to compile against, not for runtime.

For execution real implementation is needed. Because GlassFish is used anyway, using following dependency instead is suitable solution:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```